# Separate Domain users get redirected to Default domain upon login and content save

Tags: domain-access

I have set up Domain Access module in Drupal correctly, and everything works fine but with an issue. The issue is, that when a subdomain user logs in with his account from his assigned domain, he gets redirected to main domain and finds an access denied page. Then he manually goes to subdomain.domain.com and it works fine then. Similarly, if he save any node from his assigned domain, node works fine, is shown only upon his domain, but upon save, he is redirected to the main domain, and the node path is maindomain.com/urlalias, which causes him to show access denied.If he then goes to subdomain.com/urlalias of the node he just created, it shows fine without any problems. How to settle this issue, I have spent days sorting it out but still no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After plenty of fatigue , I ended up removing $base_url from settings.php and the problem was solved. But still I wonder what if I have to ever to use $base_url again, the problem will again creep up.